# I am finding it hard to identify a certain letter in a word in a string and create a true or false answer

Tags: python, string, indexing

Write a function called ‘check(name, c)’ that takes in 2 string arguments (name and c). Check
whether c is present in name 5 or more times. If so, print True, otherwise False.
• Eg: calling check(‘hello’, ‘e’) should print false (‘e’ is present less than 5 times in ‘hello’),
but check(‘hiiiii’ , ‘i’) should print True

```
def check(name,c):
    if check.find('name'c,[-3]
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: You need to provide the code you have come up with so far.

Comment: You are expected to provide a *honest* attempt (please read [ask]). This is a syntactically incorrect code, and it does not try to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy and straight forward:

You just have to iterate through every character of your string (`name`) and compare it with `c`.
If it matches update the count.
At last check if the count is greater than or equal to 5

```
def check(name, c):
  no_of_times_c_is_present = 0
  for i in name:
    if i==c:
      no_of_times_c_is_present+=1
  return no_of_times_c_is_present>=5

print (check("hello", "e"))
print (check("hiiiii", "i"))
```